# Groovy domain class find with only provided filter

Tags: grails, groovy

*Hello*

I need to perform Domain class filtering in Groovy for provided filter fields.
Here is code sample:

```
User.findAll(name: filter.name, age: filter.age, department: filter.department)
```

Is there exists some syntax sugar to help me to validate if for example **filter.name** is not provided e.g. null or empty - do not filter by this field. Thanks.

Comment: You can  use the criteria query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abs has right. Here is an example with if-statements for not provided filter fields:

```
User.createCriteria().list {
  if (filter.name)       eq("name", filter.name)
  if (filter.age)        eq("age", filter.age)
  if (filter.department) eq("department", filter.department)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply the sugar right on the arguments map (assuming filter is a Map):

```
def args = filter.collectEntries{ k, v -> 
  [ 'age', 'name', 'department' ].contains( k ) && v ? [ (k):v ] : Collections.EMPTY_MAP 
}
def users = User.findAll args
```